# Error enabling TokuDB - Percona Server not running with jemalloc enabled

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, percona

I have installed:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-63-generic x86_64)
- Percona Server 5.6.26-74.0-1.trusty
- Percona Server TokuDB 5.6.26-74.0-1.trusty
- libjemalloc1 3.6.0-2.trusty

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` under `[mysqld_safe]` I have added:
`malloc-lib = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1`

I have restarted the server.

Each time I run `sudo ps_tokudb_admin --enable -u root -p` I get:

> Checking if Percona Server is running with jemalloc enabled... ERROR:
>   Percona Server is not running with jemalloc, please restart mysql
>   service to enable it and then run this script...

Comment: Have you tried installing Percona Server 5.6 with TokuDB using official Percona repository?
Did you try starting with
`LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libjemalloc.so.1 /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: @jerichorivera The install is from the official Percona repository. I have not tried starting it with that command. I will give that a try.

Comment: @jerichorivera I am starting to suspect that it may be because I installed MySQL as part of the Ubuntu install before installing Percona server? I tried a Ubuntu install on a separate virtual machine without installing MySQL. When I tried to install TokuDB from the repository I got an error that seemed to indicate that it could not find the version of TokuDB matching that of the Percona server. However downloading and installing the latest version of TokuDB from the website seemed to work and the `ps_tokudb_admin` command succeeded after that.